# Is there a way to autopopulate a mongoose field with a string?

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, auto-populate

I have a `Item` schema with an array of categories where I store some `id`s :

```
const schema = new Schema<Item>(
...
categories:[
 {
   type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
   ref: 'Category',
   autopopulate: { select:'name'}
 }
]
...
)
```

Category:

```
const schema = new Schema<Category>({
  slug: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    index: true,
  },
  name:{
    type: String,
    required:true,
  }
});
```

and I am using the `mongoose-autopopulate` package at the moment.

Is there a way to replace the `ids` in the `Item` schema with the appropriate `name` when queried (with or without `mongoose-autopopulate`) ?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is to use `.populate` with an object passed in. I found this in the `mongoose` documentation

```
// The 2nd `populate()` call below overwrites the first because they
// both populate 'fans'.
Story.
  find().
  populate({ path: 'fans', select: 'name' }).
  populate({ path: 'fans', select: 'email' });
// The above is equivalent to:
Story.find().populate({ path: 'fans', select: 'email' });
```

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

In your case I think you need to use `.populate({ path: 'categories', select: 'name' });`

Comment: Isn't it the same as I have right now ? using the `autopopulate: { select:'name'}` key in the schema ?

Comment: Oh you are right.... did not read your question well, I think to you can use `.virtual` for this, I have personally not used this before but when looking through the documentation this seems to be able to populate fields based on other values than `ids`

Comment: To get a clear understanding of what you want, you want to save an `Item` with the `categories` property not having the `_id`s to refer to the `Category` but the `name` to refer to the category right?

Comment: Yes, I want to retrieve an `Item` but the `categories` are replaced by `name`s instead of `_id`s.

Comment: So you want it to be saved in the database as just `_id`s like it is supossed to but a query where you get the `categories` as an array of strings with the `name`?

Comment: I think autoPopulate does not support what you are trying to do I think my answer is still valid if you query it like this it should returns it like my question is above this.

Comment: I made my research too, I didn't find any solution for my question and I don't think there is one at the moment, maybe in the future it will be possible. but hey thank you for the help.

Comment: I think it is possible with `.populate` but not with `autopopulate`, also the way it is used is passing it to a field like you are doing but giving it a `Boolean` value.